# django pass data using anchor tag

Tags: django

I am trying to pass data using anchor tag to django views.
My html file:

```
    <div class="card-body dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Pay</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="{% url 'payments' data='wallet'%}">Payments Wallet</a>
        <a href="{% url 'payments' data='credit_card'%}">Payments Credit card</a>
        <a href="{% url 'payments' data='debitcard'%}">Payments Debitcard</a>
        <a href="{% url 'payments' data='bitcoin'%}">Payments Bitcoin</a>
      </div>
    </div>    
  </div>
```

My urls.py file

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('payments/<str:data>',views.payments,name="payments"),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root =  settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

my views.py file

```
def payments(request):
    query = request.GET.get('data')
    print(query)
    return render(request, '403.html')
```

Error : Reverse for 'payments' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['customerspayments\/(?P[^/]+)$']

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are passing parameter to url, you have to add that argument to function too. So, either change your `views.py` only, just by adding a parameter inside function

### 1. Best way

```
# Edit

# Pass parameter like this, if it works or not, for all 4 anchors
<a href="{% url 'payments' wallet %}">Payments Wallet</a>


# Add data to the side of reqeust
def payments(request, data):
    # If you getting query like this, then you don't have to pass parameter to url
    # query = request.GET.get('data')
    query = data

    print(query)
    return render(request, '403.html')
```

Or, if you want to get parameter from get method, then change url. So, ether you take from get method like:

### 2. Another way

```
# urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    # removed data
    path('payments',views.payments,name="payments"),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root =  settings.MEDIA_ROOT)


# Your template where, your anchor is
<div class="card-body dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Pay</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="{% url 'payments' %}?data=wallet">Payments Wallet</a>
        <a href="{% url 'payments' %}?data=credit_card">Payments Credit card</a>
        <a href="{% url 'payments' %}?data=debitcard">Payments Debitcard</a>
        <a href="{% url 'payments' %}?data=bitcoin">Payments Bitcoin</a>
      </div>
    </div>    
  </div>


# views.py
# your views.py
def payments(request):
    query = request.GET.get('data')
    print(query)
    return render(request, '403.html')
```

Comment: Mam still not working seems my url format is wrong.

Comment: I have edited code for first one. Check that one if that works or not. If not edit your question with full tracebacks!!!