# How Can I execute search function after click on specific category name?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I have some book category names within `Anchor tags` on the home page. If a user clicks on a specific category, I want to show them all the books of that category. But I can't get an idea to pass the name of the category from Anchor tag through `url.py` to `views.py` and then execute the **search function**.
**`home.html`**

```
<ul class="book-catagory">
    <li class="list-item">
        <a href="{% url 'home' %}">Philosophy</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
        <a href="{% url 'home' %}">Litereture</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
        <a href="{% url 'home' %}">Computer Science</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
        <a href="{% url 'home' %}">Electrical</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**`path in url.py`**

```
path('',views.home, name='home')
```

**`views.py`**

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        searchName = request.POST.get('searchBook')
        if not searchName :
             searchName = ""
        
        context={
            'data': Book.objects.filter(bookname__contains=searchName)
        }
        return render(request, 'library_site/home.html',context)
    else:
        context={
            'data': Book.objects.all()
        }           
    return render(request, 'library_site/home.html',context)
```

Comment: This should help i think:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61658567/django-pass-data-using-anchor-tag

Comment: I followed the Best Way that he mentioned, but getting this error "home() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'"

Answer (score 0):

views.py

def Book1(request):
category=['1']

```
books= Product.objects.filter(category=category)

context = {'books':books}
return render(request, 'store/store.html', context)
```

urls.py

urlpatterns = [

```
path('book1/', views.Book1, name='book1')

]
```

models.py
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField

class Book(models.Model):
MY_CHOICES = ((1, 'book1'),
(2, 'book2'),

```
          )

category = MultiSelectField(choices=MY_CHOICES,
                     max_choices=4,
                     max_length=30,null=True,blank=True)
```